# UITabBar attachment view, conform to hidesBottomBarWhenPushed

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

How can we attach a view to a `UITabBar` or `UITabBarController` and allow it to conform to things like `"Hide bottom bar on push"`? Any view that gets added to the `UITabBarController` will a part of the `UINavigationController`, meaning that the view will not take part in the tab bar animation, and will simply be left visible after a push.

Is it frowned upon to subclass `UITabBar` itself, and if not, how would we handle the subviews of it? My attachment is located behind the tab bar and becomes visible when needed (like Spotify's or Apple Music's player bar), which causes problems when iOS automatically moves the z-index of the tab bar during these situations.

Comment: Sure, then consider a subview of a UITabBarController instead. Is there any way to make it seem as if it is part of the tab view, in the scenario where you push a view controller and the tab view hides? We could probably achieve this using custom animations and replicating the native timings, but we would have to juggle the z-index of the view

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your initial comment. You are right, I was mistaken about the Music app. I might try to perform a custom animation on navigationController:willShowViewController:animated: before rewriting the tab bar controller. Thanks for the feedback, and for all of your books (which are awesome).

Comment: Thanks, but I’m afraid they don’t go in for this sort of complicated trickery. The frameworks try hard to give us a set of tools and invite us to use them normally, as intended, and I mostly subscribe to that. That’s why this extra view that comes and goes with the tab bar seems such an odd thing to want, to someone so narrow minded as I am!

Comment: Of course if it’s another subview of the tab bar controller you could try to use autolayout to pin it to the tab bar! But I’ve no idea if that would work. It might just break the whole interface.

Comment: I've tried doing that, but there seem to be some undocumented things going on during the transition of the tab bar, causing views to jump around every now and then. Why is there no such thing as a UITabBarAttachmentView? Every audio-based app has implemented their own version of one. (Obviously, it's not difficult unless you want to do the weird stuff I want to do)